# Replacing numerical values in a FASTA file with their index in a different file. (Bash preferred)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, fasta, character-replacement

I have a folder full of fasta files with the following format (and so on), where the line beginning with > is the read name of DNA sequence, and the following line is the sequence itself. This pattern repeats for the entire file:

```
> 887_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq1
GGCCCGCCTCCCGTCGGCCGGTGCGAGCGGCTCCGCGA
> 55_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq2
GGGGGGGGCGTCTCGCGCAAACGTCCATAAC
> ...
...
```

In the read names, [887] corresponds to the index of a query sequence I used to find this read, stored in a different file (e.g. SequenceNames.txt). The other file can be assumed to have this format:

```
SequenceA
SequenceB
...
```

I want to replace only the number between > and _ (avoiding incidental matches with the filename) with the Sequence matching the index of that number from the SequenceNames file. For example, I would want

```
> 1_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq1
ACTATC
> 2_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq1
```

to become

```
> SequenceA_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq1
> SequenceB_ENCFF899MTI.fastq.gz_seq1
```

I am able to make these replacements generally, but I'm really unsure of how to direct the index replacement specifically to the location/regex match between > and _ without performing a file-wide dictionary replacement of these numbers, and I'm struggling with awk array indexing to get something like

```
gawk '{print gensub(/^> ([0-9]*)_/,array[pattern],"\\1")}'
```

to produce what I'm looking for.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result corresponding to the provided sample inputs

Comment: Reformatted a bit. Hopefully that's more clear?

Comment: `1` / `2` => `A` / `B` is somewhat clear; what isn't clear is the first sample of `887` and `15`; if the file contains only 2 lines with the values `887` and `15` .... are these numbers supposed to be replaced with whatever is at lines #887 and #15 from the 2nd file ... or do we replace `887` (1st line in file) with whatever is in the 1st line of the 2nd file, and replace `15` (2nd line of file) with whatever is in the 2nd line of the 2nd file?

Comment: the current `gawk` code is incomplete, eg, how are you populating the variable `pattern` and the array `array[]`?

Comment: In all honesty, that's what I'm struggling with. The goal is your first understanding -- that numbers 887 and 15 would correspond to the 887th and 15th entries in the Names file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gawk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ar["> "NR"_"]=$0} 
NR>FNR{match($0,/^> [0-9]+_/,m); gsub(/^> [0-9]+_/, "> " ar[m[0]]"_", $0);print} ' SequenceNames.txt matches.fasta
```

The `NR==FNR` block collects line data from the sequence name file in an array indexed with a string built from ">", the line number, and the trailing "_" character.

The `NR>FNR` block stores the string matched to a regex requiring the line-start ">" followed by a space, a number, and the underscore in array `m`. Gsub is then used to replace the match with the corresponding value held in the sequence name array.

Tested using GNU Awk 5.1.0

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked perfectly. Also really appreciate the by-line runthrough.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  seqVal[FNR]=$0
  next
}
/^>/ && match($0,/(^> )[^_]*(_.*$)/,arr){
  print arr[1] seqVal[++count] arr[2]
}
' sequencenames.txt input.fasta
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the desire is to replace the number in a line of the fasta file that starts `> 887_` with content of the 887th line of `SequenceNames.txt`, then:

```
awk '
    # create lookup table
    NR==FNR { i2p[FNR] = $0; next }

    # try to change relevant lines
    $1==">" {

        # extract index
        idx = $2
        sub( /_.+/, "", idx )

        # try to replace (no change if no match)
        if (idx in i2p)
            sub( /^[^_]+/, "> "i2p[idx] )
    }

    # print all lines
    1
' SequenceNames.txt input.fasta >output.fasta
```

Comment: The updated version of this also seems to work. Really much appreciated, and useful to have two similar (but different) approaches to learn from.